# Восстановление после git reset --hard

Tags: git, github

Случайно использовал git reset --hard в своем проекте без каких-либо коммитов.

Что я делал:

Сделал небольшой проект, добавил файлы в git add .
Хотел сделать коммит, но не увидел, что git просит от меня git config -- global user.email и user.name

Ничего не закоммитилось и я случайно прописал git reset --hard, думая, что у меня есть последний коммит. Удалилось вообще все. Как это все вернуть? Бекапов нет.

Comment: Никак. . . . . .

Comment: Просто интересно, как можно **случайно** написать git reset - hard?

Comment: если вызывалось git add, то файлы попали в .git/objects. далее git cat -p и смотреть содержимое. https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-Git

Answer (score 1):

должно помочь

git reset --hard HEAD@{1}

эта команда откатывает последнее действие

Comment: Без коммитов эта команда выдаст ошибку

Comment: согласен, нужно посмотреть журнал

git reflog

Comment: Без коммитов журнал будет пустой

Answer (score -1):

То есть, не имея коммита, ты сбросил последние изменения?
Вернуть это можно путём восстановления файлов проекта, но не при помощи гит, а при помощи программ восстанавливающих утраченные файлы, что очень трудно и долго.

Comment: Да, без коммита скинул последние изменения.... Мда

Comment: но практически, если изменений не много, то проще ручками... + будет урок коммитить отлучку в туалет

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант - в phpstorm можно восстановить локальные изменения. ПКМ по папке проекта - Local History - Show History

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/786867)

Comment: @DanilApsadikov почему не содержится решение? Решение как раз по шагам и прописано...